# Origin of the phrase "You're either very brave, or very stupid"

Tags: dialogue, origin, trope

> You're either very brave, or very stupid

It's a common as dirt line from basically every action or drama movie ever, some examples from the top of my head would be [Spooks S05E08- Agenda](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0895581/), [Star Trek DS9 S05E23- Blaze of Glory](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708506/) and [Red Dwarf: S06E03- Gunmen of the Apocalypse](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0684158/) (*mighty* instead of *very*, to fit in with the western theme of the episode).

I've had a google around but I couldn't find any information on this, and surprisingly TVTropes doesn't have a page for it.

Does anyone know where this phrase came from? It must be something famous because it shows up everywhere. From those I remember the earliest is Red Dwarf in 1993, so that's the number to beat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a book from 1945:

> The pilot was either very brave or very stupid

http://books.google.ie/books?id=TvsDAAAAYAAJ&q=%22very+brave+or+very+stupid%22&dq=%22very+brave+or+very+stupid%22&hl=ga&sa=X&ei=9Y68U9bSNoWI7AbZgYHoCQ&redir_esc=y

Experiment with [Google n-gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=either%20very%20brave%20or%20very%2Cvery%20brave%20or%20very%20stupid&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceither%20very%20brave%20or%20very%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20brave%20or%20very%20stupid%3B%2Cc0) to find other/closer versions of the quote.

Answer (score 1):

I think [The Sea Hawk (1940)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033028/) might qualify as an origin, at least in film.

> You were very brave, trying to take this ship single-handed.
>
> Thank you, sir.
>
> Brave but stupid.

[Source](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/M13172694/The+Sea+Hawk/Brave+but+stupid.)

I would venture to guess that something very similar was written in a book long before.

Comment: I think that dialogue is a bit too different from the very common phrase the questioin asks about.

Comment: That's saying "brave _and_ stupid", not "brave _or_ stupid".